# Calculating a limit, and making a small assumption

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Hi guys I wanted to get feedback on my work. I am trying to calculate the following

$$\lim _{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cot(\pi t)\sin(t) }{2\sec(t)}$$

My approach was to expand this in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$, then I know that if a limit exists it behaves well under multiplication

\begin{align*}
 \lim _{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cot(\pi t)\sin(t) }{2\sec(t)} &= \lim _{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos(\pi t)}{\sin(\pi t)}\cdot \frac{\sin(t)\cos(t)}{2}\\
&= \lim _{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos(\pi t)}{\sin(\pi t)} \cdot \lim _{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(t)\cos(t)}{2}\\
&= \lim _{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos(\pi t)}{\sin(\pi t)}  \cdot 0\\
&=0
\end{align*}

My issue is that I am assuming the limit exists. I would appreciate feedback's and other cool ways to approach this. Thank you

Comment: This doesn't quite work -- you need BOTH limits to exist for the limit to behave well over multiplication, but the first limit here is undefined (it is $-\infty$ from the left and $\infty$ from the right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea:

$$\frac{\cot\pi t\sin t}{2\sec t}=\frac{\cos\pi t}{\sin\pi t}\frac{\cos t\sin t}2=$$

$$=\frac1{2\pi}\frac{\pi t}{\sin\pi t}\frac{\sin t}t\cos t\cos\pi t\xrightarrow[t\to0]{}\frac1{2\pi}\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1=\frac1{2\pi}$$

Comment: Why do you have that $\cos\pi t\to-1$ as $t\to0$?

Comment: @NickPeterson Mistake. Thanks, edited

Answer (score 1):

There are several terms here that are either constant or have non-zero limits.  So, in reality, what you need to worry about here is finding
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin(t)}{\sin(\pi t)}.
$$
This is an indeterminate form, as both the numerator and denominator tend to $0$ as $t\to0$.  Why not try applying L'Hospital's rule?

Once you have this limit, you can easily combine that with the limits of the cosine terms and constants to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

There's no indetermination if you rewrite the expression as
$$\frac{\cos\pi t\sin t}{\sin\pi t\cdot\dfrac2{\cos t}}=\frac14\cos\pi t \,\frac{\sin 2t}{\sin \pi t}\xrightarrow[\;t\to 0\;]{} \frac14\cdot 1\cdot\frac2\pi=\frac1{2\pi}.$$